# Difference between C# and VB.Net custom classes

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have been out of VB.Net way too long, I have a custom class in C# that needs to be converted to VB.Net and would like to know the main differences between them. Certain things in C# I cannot seem to do in Vb.Net with classes such as use: public classname or public [classname](DataTable dt) in VB.net

My class looks like the following:

```
public class subcontractor
{
    public int organization_id { get; set; }
    public int subcontractor_id { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public List<evaluationpoint> points { get; set; }

    public subcontractor() { }
    public subcontractor(DataTable dt)
    {
        organization_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["organization_id"].ToString());
        subcontractor_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["subcontractor_id"].ToString());
        project_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["project_id"].ToString());
        points = new List<evaluationpoint>();
        foreach ( DataRow dr in dt.Rows )
        { points.Add(new evaluationpoint(dr)); }
    }

    public class evaluationpoint
    {
        public int category_id { get; set; }
        public int eval_id { get; set; }
        public int rating { get; set; }

        public evaluationpoint() { }
        public evaluationpoint(DataRow dr)
        {
            category_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["category_id"].ToString());
            eval_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["eval_id"].ToString());
            rating = Convert.ToInt32(dr["rating"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What are the differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx)

Constructors in VB.NET are different syntactically:

C#

```
Class Foo
{
    public Foo( int arg ) { }
}
```

VB

```
Class Foo
    Public Sub New( ByVal arg as Integer )

    End Sub
End Class
```

You can for the most part do anything in VB.NET that you can in C#, you are just going to have to change your syntax appropriately.  There is plenty of reference material out there, make use of it.

Comment: it has just been so long since I have been involved in VB that these things slip from memory if not used enough. I know syntax is greatly different, just forgot how to instatiate a new class within itself, thank you

Comment: @Guffa: I don't use VB often as you can tell :)  Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If your project is implementing in VB.NET, you other projects (even the C# ones) can still call the VB.NET methods all the same (and vice versa).

A single Visual Studio solution can have VB.NET projects and C# projects. Each (with the proper project references) can access the other's methods and classes since they're all .NET classes that have been compiled into MSIL for the CLR to run.

Comment: I need to actually take the c# class and implement it into a VB.Net project. Are you saying that I can simply take the C# class and place it into my VB.Net project with no issues?

Comment: No, what you could do is add a C# library project to your solution, add your C# classes to that project and then add a reference to that project from your VB.net project. Then you can access your C# classes from within the VB.net project and you won't have to rewrite anything.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for constructors is rather different; in C# you use the class name, in VB you use New, for example

```
Class SubContractor

   Public Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Sub New(dt As DataTable)
   End Sub

End Class
```

There's more specific details on the differences, including constructor/destructor differences on this [cheat sheet](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html#constructorsdestructors).